# Gcloud Pub/Sub: Total timeout of API google.pubsub.v1.Publisher exceeded 60000 milliseconds before any response was received

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm trying to publish messages from the cloud function to the cloud Pub/Sub topic using their [NodeJS client package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/pubsub). I'm facing the below error:

```
Total timeout of API google.pubsub.v1.The publisher exceeded 60000 milliseconds before any response was received.
```

Solutions I have tried:

1. Increased timeout from 60 seconds to 600 seconds in pub/sub client.
2. Increased CPU and RAM for cloud functions.
3. Used batch messaging for efficiency.
4. Create a single topic instance and use it across all messages.
5. Tried to avoid cold start.
6. Tried with admin permission.
7. I tried avoiding JSON messages and publishing buffers.

Here is my code used to publish messages:

```js
export class FeedService {
  private static instance: FeedService;
  private pubsubClient: PubSub;
  private feedTopic: Topic;
  private maxMessages = 50;
  private maxMilliseconds = 10000;
  private messagePromises: Promise<string>[] = [];

  constructor() {
    this.pubsubClient = new PubSub({
      projectId: process.env.PROJECT_ID,
      credentials: {
        client_email: process.env.GOOGLE_CLOUD_CLIENT_EMAIL,
        private_key: process.env.GOOGLE_CLOUD_CLIENT_PRIVATE_KEY,
      },
    });
  }

  public static getInstance() {
    if (!FeedService.instance) {
      FeedService.instance = new FeedService();
    }

    return FeedService.instance;
  }

  // provide global topic instance
  private getFeedTopic() {
    if (!this.feedTopic) {
      this.feedTopic = this.pubsubClient.topic(process.env.FEED_TOPIC_ID, {
        batching: {
          maxMessages: this.maxMessages,
          maxMilliseconds: this.maxMilliseconds,
        },
      });
    }

    return this.feedTopic;
  }

  // Calling this function to publish messages
  async pushNotificationForAggregation(payload: FeedTypes.FeedQueuePayload) {
    try {
      const messageOptions: MessageOptions = {
        json: payload,
        publishTime: {
          seconds: Date.now() / 1000,
        },
      };

      // store promises
      this.messagePromises.push(
        this.getFeedTopic().publishMessage(messageOptions)
      );

      return { success: true };
    } catch (error: any) {
      logger.error(
        `[Failed to push feed to queue] [${payload.userId}]: ${error?.message}`
      );

      return { success: false };
    }
  }

  // await all promises before sending HTTP response 
  async processRemainingMessages() {
    try {
      const messages = await Promise.all(this.messagePromises);

      return { success: true, messages };
    } catch (error: any) {
      logger.error(
        `[Failed to process remaining messages] : ${error?.message}`
      );

      return { success: false };
    }
  }
}
```

**Updates**

I have tried the same code with the cloud run instead of the cloud function, and it works fine there.

So I can confirm there are no issues with the code.

Comment: Hi @Alish, Could you confirm, what is the version of the Pub/Sub that you are using ?

Comment: Hi, for the package google-cloud/pubsub, I'm using 4.1.1.

Comment: Did you check this similar [GitHub issue](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-pubsub/issues/1442) ? Let me know if this helped you or not.

Comment: Yes, I have checked this and tried the solutions mentioned there. Here is a link to my comment in the same discussion: https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-pubsub/issues/1442#issuecomment-1972815216

Comment: It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP [support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/). Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) describing your issue.

Comment: There has been a similar issue open for a long time in the issue tracker.

Comment: There can be many different causes of such an issue related to environment, which is why a support case would be a better place to explore the cause for your instance of this problem. If you are using Cloud Functions, you'd have to specify all of the runtime settings you have configured for us to have a complete picture in the context of this question.

Comment: I have created an issue in GCP support. I will update here or answer my question if I find anything.

Comment: @KamalAboul-Hosn I have tried the same code with the cloud run instead of the cloud function, and it works fine there. So I can confirm there are no issues with the code.

Comment: @KamalAboul-Hosn the problem was in environment variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue. The problem was with environmental variables. Google Cloud functions parse each variable added from the GUI console, and ads escape sequences. So `\n` in my service account's private will be converted to `\\n` resulting in wrong secrets.

It's strange that the Pub/Sub SDK does not return proper error messages; it always returns an API timeout, no matter how much time I increase the timeout.

Removing escape sequences from the account's private key solves the problem.

Comment: So you removed `\n` from the key. How did that work? This also changed the key right

Comment: Also, How did you find this solution? I mean what made you think of changing key

Comment: I have tried deploying a minimal working sample and was doing it for testing I have added env variables directly into the code instead of configuring them. Then it worked, so I eliminated one-by-one variables and finally discovered the problem with private keys.

Answer (score 0):

This issue got resolved when I upgraded to version 4.3.3